# Unable to instantiate application com.my.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse

My application compiles and I go to run and immediately the app crashes and I get this error in logcat

```
Unable to instantiate application com.my.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

So it seems like for some reason the app can't find one of my classes. I have no idea why this is happening, the .java file exists in that location.

What's really odd is that I sent the exact same code to a co-worker and he was able to compile and run with no problem at all. I've tried on 3 different computers and different versions of Eclipse and have had no success. He also tried the apk I made on his phone and it didn't work. He seems to think it's an environment issue. Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: if you have updated adt to rev 22 right click on your project. goto properties. java build path. order export tab. Make sure Android private libraries is checked. Clean and build. Try this

Comment: It only takes 10 minutes for StackOverflow to solve my problem :) Thank you so much!!! You have no idea how much time you saved me. If you want to turn that into an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: I wish @Raghunandan's comment was a posted answer so I can upvote it! It solved my issue. Oh well, upvoted the comment.